# Top level list items only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to insert an icon into `<li>` if that items contains another `<ul>`.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>    
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$('ul:first > li').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('ul').length > 0) {
        $(this).find('a').prepend('<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>');
    }
});
```

Unfortunately currently I get it inserted in every `<li>` of the second `<ul>` as well. How do I keep it to the top level only?

```js
$('ul:first > li').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('ul').length > 0) {
        $(this).find('a').prepend('<i class="fa fa-caret-down">ICON </i>');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>    
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`:has()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/), `$('ul:first > li:has(ul)')`, to select the `li` if it has a child `ul` element.

In addition, you would need to use the direct child selector within the `.find()` method so that only direct `a` child elements are selected `$(this).find('>a')`.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/fwn0r2wz/)

```
$('ul:first > li:has(ul)').each(function() {
    $(this).find('>a').prepend('<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>');
});
```

Comment: Brilliant! Love the simplicity!